# How do PING responses disabled from different subnets?

Tags: networking, windows-10, firewall, ping, icmp

I found that:

1. I can ping my Windows box `A` from another computer `B` in the same subnet.

   This implies, that echo server is running.
2. I can open remote desktop on `A` from another computer `C` in another subnet.

   This implies, that network routing is configured correctly.
3. I can't ping `A` from `C` while Firewall is ON.
4. I can ping `A` from `C` if firewall is OFF.

   This implies that there is a rule in Firewall, which allows pinging from local subnet, but disables pinging from different subnets.

What is this rule? How to find it?

Comment: I suspect what version of windows is entirely relevant here.

Comment: Have added version-specific tags...

Comment: What you said is not completely correct: you inferred from the ability of pc C to RDP into A that routing will allow all sorts of traffic. It needn't. It might allow only certain protocols, or certain ports, or any mixture thereof. ICMP (the `ping` protocol) might be disabled at the gateway level, or (since it is port-less) might be excluded because it does not use ports so and so. You can eliminate this posisbility by checking the router's settings, or by using pcs (Linux) which **certainly** do not bar ICMP by default.

Comment: I eliminated this possibility by observing `A`'s subnet with Wireshark: I see request packages there, but see no responses.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: https://bitlaunch.io/blog/how-to-make-windows-10-pingable/. This page mentions the specific Windows screens to pass to get to the specific dialog where that setting can be made. By default, indeed, it is on "local subnet".

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answers as the linked site might change, rendering your answer useless. Instead please quote the most important parts and include the link for reference only.